# Python creates a redundant reference to a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, garbage-collection

I observe a strange behavior with Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2:

```
import sys

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.bar
    def bar(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
print(sys.getrefcount(f) - 1) # subtract the extra reference created by
                              # passing a reference to sys.getrefcount.
```

When I run the code in python I get 2 which means that there are two references to the Foo object. The only solution is to remove `self.b = self.bar`. It seems to create a cycle reference.

Can anyone explain the behavior?

**UPDATE:**
Here are the run results:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.bar

    def bar(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        print "deleted"

def test_function():
    f = Foo()
    print f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in xrange(5):
        test_function()
    print "finished"
```

---

```
python ./test.py
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x104797e60>
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x104797ef0>
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x104797f38>
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x104797f80>
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x104797fc8>
finished
```

As you may see on every iteration python creates a new instance of the class Foo, but never releases them!

**UPDATE 2** AND THE ROOT CAUSE

> Objects that have **del**() methods and are part of a reference cycle
>   cause the entire reference cycle to be uncollectable, including
>   objects not necessarily in the cycle but reachable only from it.
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage

Foo class instance has both a `__del__` method and the bound method `self.b = self.bar` which means it is definitely a part of the reference cycle.
Thus, according to py docs the instance is **uncollectable**!

Comment: Are you saying that Foo never gets collected? Can you provide code that demonstrates that this is the case? Just printing the refcount isn't convincing, because objects with nonzero refcounts can still get collected.

Comment: @Kevin, please find the results in the update.

Comment: @fsqirrel well the `__del__` function does not delete, that it has to call super().__del__ or you just make del about, not 100% sure but worth a try

Comment: Thanks for posting your results. I get the same output as you when I run your code in 2.7, but when I port it to 3.X (changing the print statements to functions, and xrange to range), the "deleted" messages appear after "finish". I wouldn't depend on this always happening even in 3.X, though, since the docs say "It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits." I was going to suggest calling `gc.collect()` manually just before the end of your program, but curiously that didn't seem to affect the outcome in 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra reference is hidden in the bound method stored in `f.b`.

```
print(f.b.__self__) # <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001CD147FEF98>
```

When storing `self.b = self.bar`, you create a bound method. A bound method keeps track of the instance to which it is bound. This is what allows it to pass `self` implicitly.

The same would happen if you were to manually create the bound method.

```
import sys

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
print(sys.getrefcount(f) - 1) # 1

bound_method = f.bar

print(sys.getrefcount(f) - 1) # 2
```

So you are correct: instantiating a bound method creates the reference cycle `f -> f.b -> f`. Although, this is not an issue since Python handles cyclic reference since [version 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20091214142515/http://www.amk.ca/python/2.0).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply and detailed explanation!

Comment: @fsquirrel you seemed to mention in another comment that your Foo instance is not collected? Did this help solve the issue? And if it didn't are you using a c extension, or implementing some custom `__del__`` method?

Comment: As far as I know, we have no extensions. But the class does have a custom `__del__` method. It makes calls to `os.fdclose`.
Does it prevent the garbage collection?
Yes, your solution solves the issue:)

Comment: Please find the results of the test run in the update.